# notation for different versions of melody

Tags: notation, melody

I have a simple song for which I know two melodies to play. They are not played simultaneously - one has to choose between one of them.

**What is the common/standard notation for that?**

As far as I know, a piece of music where two melodies are played simultaneously (by different instruments) is written like this:

[image: Two melodies for same lyrics, presented as if two instruments on single score]

So how would it look like (in standard notation) if the two melodies are alternatives, not both part of the music?

And if both melodies have a name (e.g. "Foo's version" and "Bar's version" named after the two componists Foo and Bar), where would these names be written?

Comment: As a clarification: are you also scoring an accompaniment that is identical for both melodies? That is, is including both melodies in a single score the most efficient way to notate the song, as opposed to just writing it out twice?

Comment: @Aaron What you see in the picture is the whole song (two versions of it), so no, there is no portion of music shared between both. Or, in fact there is: the first three notes and the last two.

Comment: Totally irrelevant to the question, but: as Albrecht noted, the metric emphasis of the text demands that the first note be a pickup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the brevity of the melody and the fact that there are no other parts involved, the best way to write it would be as though it were two different songs. That affords the greatest visual clarity and eliminates any uncertainty over whether there are two parts to be sung together or perhaps a main melody and a secondary melody (as opposed to two equal options).

[image: Melodies notated separately on single page]

Whether the lyrics are included separately from the notes as in the above example or included with each melody is according to taste.

Answer (score 6):

When just an occasional note is different, a bracketed cue-sized note may be sufficient (example A).    In your case, however, I think there are enough differences to warrant an ossia stave (example B).  Maybe even a full-sized one, if the two versions are of equal status.

Either way, some explanatory text would be in order, to make it clear that the ossia is an alternative, not to be simultaneously performed!

[image]

Comment: So you say there is no difference in notation between "play those two melodies simultaneously" and "choose one of those two melodies". So how would a musician know which is the case? You say some explanatory text would be in order - how would that look like? Is that totally up to me or is there some standard? If yes, can you update your picture accordingly?

Comment: I'm surprised that the conversation thus far hasn't involved the marking "[Ossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossia)." Both of the options shown above would be great in a situation in which one version is the default or preferred version, and another is an alternative. Personally, if both options are meant to be equal, I'd go with Aaron's option, with some text instructions about choosing.

Comment: The song is in F maj., missing Bb signature an up-beating.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Since the song contains only notes that are present in C major, why should I make it F major? (Sorry if this is a dumb question, but my knowledge of music notation is ... limited.) I agree about the prelude, but if I use a prelude, I can't put the whole song into one line (can't repeat whole block). For reasons, space goes before correct notation, in this case.

Comment: @Kjara Correct notation **must** be paramount, otherwise you are not notating what you want. Players will play what they see. Where the barline comes is important in articulation and expression, and the right key-signature aids singers in particular to know when they have reached "home", and accompanists to create an accompaniment from just the melody. And [it's not difficult to get right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCsBj.png), and takes up no more space.

Comment: @Kjara The existing notes are _also_ present in F major. But, more importantly, the melody _sounds_ like it's in F: it starts and ends with keys from the F major chord, and they feature prominently throughout. This short snippet isn't enough to be certain, but if you play or hum it over an F major chord and then over a C major chord (or any other chord), you'll probably find the former sounds more natural.

Comment: @Kjara And I second the need to put barlines where they're musically meaningful, not convenient or easy to read. I once wrote a choral piece in irregular metre; however, I managed to squeeze it into 4/4 (with a few ties over barlines and the odd rest inserted), assuming it'd be easier to read. The result didn't really work, _feel_ right, or flow properly… Later, I got another chance to do it with the same choir, and notated it in irregular time (mostly 3/4, 2/4, and 4/4) according to what _felt_ right — and not only did the choir seem to find it easier to read, but it sounded far better.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for the image. I didn't know it was allowed notation to have a repeat symbol after a beat that is not "full" (no idea how that is called correctly), i.e. that only has 2/4 instead of 3/4 notes. In that case, I'll use the correct places for bars.

Comment: @Kjara When you have an anacrusis at the start, it's quite normal to shorten the last bar by the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Apart that this song has an up-beat and needs 1 flat it has to be written in 2 versions, because the accompaniment will be different:

I-I-V-I or I-V-V-I.

1. F F C F 2) F C  C F or F Gm C7 F

So you can notate the lyrics with one tune and add the second tune as supplement with the remark that  it can be played or sung alternately to the first version.